# python: Injecting a middle man to method calls

Tags: python, methods, python-mock

I would like to listen in on some calls to 3rd party library methods. Notably, I'd like to attach some sort of feedback method on these methods I am listening to. For instance, whenever logging.info(msg, *args, **kwargs) is called, I'd like to have a separate method with same parameter list fired off as well.

The closest I can find is the [mock module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)'s side_effect feature. But correct me if I am wrong, this feature will completely override the original behaviour of the function instead of tagging a function along.

Is there a module out there that can suit my needs or do I have to unceremonously hijack the functions I need?

Edit: Clarified title.

Comment: I don't know of any python package doing such a thing, but you could be able to roll your own using monkeypatching and a couple decorators...

Comment: I would advice to wrap it if at all possible. Mock will be able to do the job one way or another but it will be tricky to understand and get a clean implementation

Answer (score 4):

Hijacking isn't too hard, using decorator style methods:

```
def hijack(obj, func_name):
    orig_func = getattr(obj, func_name)
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print(orig_func, args, kwargs)
        return orig_func(*args, **kwargs)
    setattr(obj, func_name, wrapped_func)
```

With this, you can patch a class like (this would work for modules, etc. as well):

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        pass
```

You can hijack the `A.f` method like:

```
hijack(A, "f")
```

Resulting in this:

```
a = A()
a.f()
```

Producing:

```
<function A.f at 0x7fc56b034620> (<__main__.A object at 0x7fc56b01df28>,)
```

For `logging`:

```
import logging
hijack(logging, "warning")

logging.warning("hi")
```

Produces:

```
<function warning at 0x7f83355c8a60> ('hi',)
WARNING:root:hi
```

Comment: `print(orig_func, args, **kwargs)` the double asterisk should be omitted. Otherwise, the keyword arguments will be supplied to `print` function as-is.

Comment: @no1xsyzy That's correct, thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe “unceremonously”, but I think it does what you want…

```
def hook(*args, **kwargs):
  # do stuff with args and kwargs
  hook.original(*args, **kwargs)
hook.original = logging.info
logging.info = hook
```

Unless you also want to listen to calls made by 3rd party libraries too, unfortunately.